# CryptoSwift cannot use swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7.1, cryptoswift

I would like to use https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift on my swift project (my swift is 2.1 and Xcode 7.1.1). After I had completed the installation instruction (run build.sh then add the framework file to my project), I still cannot import CryptoSwift framework. Please help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `import CryptoSwift` this is the framework header, what the error u faced

Comment: yes. I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: If you want either good performance (CryptoSwift is 500 to 1000 times slower than Common Crypto) or security (CryptoSwift is a new implementation and is not well vetted) do not use CryptoSwift. Common Crypto is supplied by Apple as part of the Security.framework. If you want a  truly secure well vetted performant library use [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) which supports multiple languages and platforms.

Answer (score 3):

Add the `CryptoSwift.framework` to the `Embedded Binaries` section, instead of the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` section. Xcode will then include it in the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` section as well.

Comment: But of course the tradeoff is an extremely slow and insecure library. Why would that be a desirable choice?

Comment: The question was how to get it to work, not whether it was a good or secure choice.

Comment: Note, that is why I did not down-vote. But a good security choice is important, right? IMO we have an obligation to point out poor security practices.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all to answer. I had installed the program by using Cocoapods. Issue is solved